# Why my SSL doesn't work?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl-certificate, openssl

I've tried for several days to make a HTTPS server but I cannot make it happen, I've followed [this](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) and [this](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign_ubuntu.html) tutorial, where I make the server signed with the certificate, but when I probe the configuration, it doesn't work

Am I probing it right? I'm doing this with `localhost` but the page has no encryption

How could I make it works???

Comment: Why do you expect a certificate for an actual domain to work on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you obtained an SSL certificate for your web domain (e.g., example.com), and you are trying to access the server via a different hostname (e.g. `localhost`), then of course SSL verification will fail.. the certificate is for a different domain!

In order for your browser to show successful SSL authentication, you need to access the site with the same domain or domain wildcard as your SSL cert is certified for.